# Ubuntu touch Terminal app asks for password

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-touch, password, nexus-7

I just installed ubuntu touch latest devel on my nexus 7 2013. Everytime i open the terminal app it asks for a password. I am not talking for the root password that i read it is "ubuntu". Does anyone has a clue?

Comment: Try `ubuntu` or `phablet`.

Comment: i have tried both. The problem is that before i get access to the app there is a "pop-up" menu that asks for authentication. I didn't enter any password during installation. The ubuntu or phablet passwords doesn't work

Comment: And what about an empty password?

Comment: authentication fails with emtpy password too.

Comment: I have had this issue too. I was thinking that I didn't set a password on my new phone. Then I thought about the phone unlock code at the very start. This for me is a 4 digit set of numbers. I entered this and now I have been able to access the extra features of the file manager. I am thinking the password that you enter into your phone at the very start is the same as the root password on my Ubuntu system.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you set a passcode or passphrase lock on your phone, that is also your user password that the Terminal (and also File Manager) will ask for.

This is a security precaution, since Terminal and File Manager have permission to access all your user data, you don't want somebody picking up your unlocked phone and doing evil things with your files.

Comment: i think i had tried what you say by entering the passcode. I don't remeber for sure. The stable release doesn't have a passcode or passphrase required so that's why i had no problem. I flashed the rtm and i set a passphrase this time. Everything works like a charm. Thank you